Is there a 2D equivalent of viewer.setGhosting() in Autodesk forge viewer (APS viewer)?
When I hide elements in the 2D published views of AutoDesk forge viewers / AutoDesk Docs viewers, it still shows greyed out originals in the view. Is it possible to completely hide elements in 2D view without ghosting ?
In 3D published views, there's an option available in Settings > Appearance > Configuration > Display > Ghost hidden objects (viewer.setGhosting()).
However, I cannot find ways to control this in 2D published views.

The setGhosting() function is designed for 3D, not 2D.
Could you try visibilityManager.setNodeOff?
var dbId = "DB ID of element you want to hide";
Viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(dbId, true);

